# How to compare two objects in c#

Tags: c#

I have a method to update some customer information

```
public UpdateCustomerInformationResponse UpdateCustomerInformation(UpdateCustomerInformationRequest request)
{
var customer = new Customer
{
    FirstName = request.Customer
    LastName = request.LastName,
    MiddleInitial = request.MiddleInitial,
    CustomerEmail = request.CustomerEmail,
    UnitNumber = request.UnitNumber,
}
```

Another object

```
var fieldRequired = new FieldRequired{
FieldName = "CustomerEmail ",
IsRequired = 1
}
```

I want to compare 2 objects so that I can find out if FieldName "CustomerEmail"
is present in Customer object.

Comment: What do you mean by compare? Equality? Reference Equality? Greater/Less than? `CustomerEmail` is a property, so it is always *there*, you want to check if they are equal?

Comment: What i want is that check fieldRequired object and based on value of FieldName (in this case CustomerEmail) I assign CustomerEmail= request.CustomerEmail otherwise I don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its so simple buddy. I found a simple solution using the reflection and extnetion method just follow as below

Create a static class with the name "CompareTwoObjects" and add the code to it.

```
 public static object CompareEquals(this T objectFromCompare, T objectToCompare)//Generic method

{

 if (objectFromCompare == null && objectToCompare == null)
 return true;
 else if (objectFromCompare == null && objectToCompare != null)
 return false;
 else if (objectFromCompare != null && objectToCompare == null)
 return false;

 //Gets all the properties of the class
 PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
 foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
 {
 object dataFromCompare = objectFromCompare.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(objectFromCompare, null);
 object dataToCompare = objectToCompare.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(objectToCompare, null);
 Type type = objectFromCompare.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(objectToCompare, null).GetType();
 if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass && !prop.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.String"))
 {
 dynamic convertedFromValue = Convert.ChangeType(dataFromCompare, type);
 dynamic convertedToValue = Convert.ChangeType(dataToCompare, type);

 object result = CompareTwoObjects.CompareEquals(convertedFromValue, convertedToValue);

 bool compareResult = (bool)result;
 if (!compareResult)
 return false;
 }


 else if (!dataFromCompare.Equals(dataToCompare))
 return false;
 }

 return true;


}
```

This will give the result of two objects are having same values or not.

Usage:-
Object1.CompareEquals(Object2);

If the class object is complex also this will work. If you found any issues please post back

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague.  Is this what you are looking for?

```
if (fieldRequired.FieldName == "CustomerEmail" && fieldRequired.IsRequired == 1)
{
   CustomerEmail = request.CustomerEmail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the interface IEqualtable, then design the method Equals with the data members that you want to compare. You can see an example of this implementation below:

```
class Customer: IEquatable<Customer>
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  ...
public bool Equals(Person other)
{
  return ((FirstName == other.FirstName) &&
  (LastName == other.LastName));
}
}
```